# If event $A$ is a union of elements of $S(A)$, then $\min_{Z\in S(A):Z\subset A}P(B\mid Z)\leq P(B\mid A)$ for any event $B$

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, probability-inequalities, inequality

Let $A$ and $B$ be events in a probability space and $S(A)$ a collection of events such that $A$ is a union of some elements in $S(A)$. How could I then conclude that the conditional probabilities satisfy the inequality

$$\min_{Z\in S(A):Z\subset A}P(B\mid Z)\leq P(B\mid A)$$

(or the same with $\inf$ in place of $\min$, which might be a safer alternative)? Estimating fraction expressions is always a pain, and I don't see any immediate trick to this. So maybe there is some qualitative insight/result which can help me with this?

Comment: Hint: The smallest of any collection of non-negative numbers cannot exceed any weighted average of those numbers.

Comment: @whuber I am sorry to say that I still don't see the trick. What you say makes complete sense, but if I understood correctly your hint, I want to represent $P(B|A)$ as an average of $P(B|Z)$s over $S(A)$ with $S(A)\ni Z\subset A$.

Comment: Where does this problem come from? As I always advocated, when ask a "proof"-type question in this forum, please ensure the statement is "provable" (that is, the statement is indeed true) first.

Comment: @Zhanxiong I've abstracted the problem a bit, but using the exact wording of a book I am reading, this chain of inequalities is used at one point. It could be that the text is missing some words and/or clarity of the text could use some work.

Your critique is welcome, but it raises a question that when one encounters an unclear statement in mathematical text/article s.t. the statement can be meaningfully abstracted away from possible context dependent structures, where should you ask help to understand it? Should you always bother the original author?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is false.

Take the uniform discrete distribution on $\{b, a_1, \dotsc, a_m\}$, and let $A=\{b, a_1, \dotsc, a_m\}$, $B=\{b\}$, and $Z_i=\{b, a_i\}$ for $i\in[m]$.  Then $P(B\mid A) = 1/(m+1)$, but $P(B\mid Z_i) = 1/2$ for every $i$.

Comment: +1 Nice example!